# Tabulator 4.6.3 Filter Column Height Restore Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabulator

## The problem

After enabling header filters and disabling again, the column height is not restored.

- Is this the default behaviour?
- Is there a way to restore to normal column height?

Take a look at this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/biruktes/wak920us/24/

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

Code

```js
var filterState = false;
var tabledata = [];

var table = new Tabulator("#html-table", {
  data: tabledata, //assign data to table
  layout: "fitColumns",
  tooltips: true,
  tooltipsHeader: true,
  placeholder: "No Data Available", //display message to user on empty table
  height: "300px",
  columns: [{
    title: "ID",
    field: "itemId",
    headerFilter: false
  },]
});

function showHideFilters() {
  if (filterState == false) {
    table.updateColumnDefinition("itemId", {
      headerFilter: true
    });
    filterState = true;
  } else {
    table.updateColumnDefinition("itemId", {
      headerFilter: false
    });
    filterState = false;
  }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.6.3/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.6.3/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <button onClick="showHideFilters()">
    Show/Hide Filters
    </button>
  <div id="html-table">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the Github repo, https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2823, this is a bug.